# How to stack list of Xarrays

Tags: python, rioxarray, stack, xarray, rasterstack

I have a folder with 4 .tiff (GeoTiff) files. Each of these contains two layers (the spectral band and a mask). I'm able to create a list containig each image using `xarray.open_rasterio`.

Now I need to stack the bands of the list into a single `DataArray`. How can I do this?

```
# Path of the folder containing the .tiff files
IMG_PATH = 'D:/test_xarray/data/'

import rasterio as rio
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

# List of .tiff files
sentinel_bands = glob(f"{IMG_PATH}*B?*.tiff")
sentinel_bands.sort() # sorted list
        
ls_bands = [] # list filled with the first layer of each file
for band in sentinel_bands:
    with xr.open_rasterio(band) as b:
        ls_bands.append(b[0,]) # index 0 corresponds to the first band of each file

# Stack bands into a single DataArray
```

Data available here https://github.com/syamkakarla98/Satellite_Imagery_Analysis/tree/main/Data/sundarbans_raw_data

Comment: you need a shape of (num_of_images, width, height) right?

Comment: using [xarray.concat](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stack the array into shape (n_image, width, height), you need np.vstack.
Check out
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

For 3 bands image e.g RGB you get shape (3,width,height).

Note: width and height must be equal in all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
xr.open_mfdataset('my/files/*.nc', parallel=True)
```

Comment: Welcome GIS SE. There is an accepted answer, for this question. You can add alternate solutions, but you have to be precise in how your solution can give better outputs. You can get details from here for [writing good answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).